# Kotlin - Método retornando lista antes de carrega-la

Tags: android, kotlin

Estou com um pequeno problema. Tenho um método que preciso que carregue uma lista de objetos(no caso, uma lista de Audios) do firebase e retorne essa lista.
O problema é que o método esta retornando a lista antes mesmo de carrega-la - como eu posso resolver isso?
Segue o método:

```
fun list(): List<Audio> {
    val list: MutableList<Audio> = mutableListOf()
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("audios").get().continueWith { it ->
        val snapshot = it.result
        snapshot.children.forEach{
            val audio = it.getValue(Audio::class.java)
            audio?.let {
                list.add(it)
            }
        }
    }
    return list
}
```

Comment: Você já conferiu se o seu áudio não está vazio e por isso não esta sendo adicionado a lista?

Comment: Não é o caso, o que eu percebi é que primeiro ele retorna a lista, e depois ele executa os codigos do firebase e carrega a lista no forEach... Como um problema de thred, mas nao sei como resolver. Não sei se tem algum outro método do firebase que execute antes  de cair no return....

Comment: Hà um grande problema com este código. Em Kotlin, a criação de listas usando add é um grande não não. A razão pela qual isto é assim é porque em Kotlin, as boas prácticas mandam evitar o uso de mutabilidade. A tua função neste momento trata de encher uma lista gradualmente. Eu gostaria muito de ajudar mas para isto preciso de perceber a configuração do teu projecto. Que livrarias estás a utilizar?

Answer (score 0):

Se a sua função está retornando a lista vazia antes de retornar os dados do firebase, é provavel que a chamada do firebase é assincrona...
Então você precisa ajustar a sua função para lidar com a chamada assincrona.

Você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
suspend fun list(): List<Audio> {
    val list: MutableList<Audio> = mutableListOf()
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("audios").get().continueWith { it ->
        val snapshot = it.result
        snapshot.children.forEach{
            val audio = it.getValue(Audio::class.java)
            audio?.let {
                list.add(it)
            }
        }
        return list
    }
}
```

> Utilizando o ***suspend*** você diz ao sistema, que sua função *list()* vai ser assincrona e retornar um dado futuro.

Nunca mexi com o get do firebase, então provavelmente você vai precisar ajustar algumas coisas... Assim como preparar o local onde você chama essa função *list()* para conseguir lidar com a chamada assincrona.
Aconselho você jogar em um *LiveData* ou utilizar o *Flow*.

Um exemplo rustico utilizando o *LiveData*:

```
val minhaLista = MutableLiveData<List<Audio>>()

suspend fun list() {
    val list: MutableList<Audio> = mutableListOf()
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("audios").get().continueWith { it ->
        val snapshot = it.result
        snapshot.children.forEach{
            val audio = it.getValue(Audio::class.java)
            audio?.let {
                list.add(it)
            }
        }
        // Executa o trigger do liveData com a nova lista
        minhaLista.value = list
    }
}

minhaLista.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { list ->
  // Aqui você terá o retorno que deseja
}
```

> Removi o retorno da função pois o *LiveData* vai tratar o valor.